# How to check if matrices form the basis for a subset?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have worked out a solution to a hw problem, but it felt too easy. That always means I'm wrong.
Here's the question...

Consider the subspace S of 2×2 symmetric matrices. Show that the following three matrices form a basis for S

a = [1 0 0 0] b = [0 1 1 0] c = [0 0 0 1], where that is read as a 2x2 matrix with the first two numbers the first row and the second row the second two numbers.

From what I can understand, you check for independence, and if they're linearly independent (not equaling the zero vector) they form a basis.

So I added them. I did not get the zero vector. So based off that, I would answer they form a basis.
I'm not confident about this at all though.

Here's my work.[image: Work]

Reworked.

[image]

Comment: You should use other *coefficients* not only $1$ when forming their *linear combination*.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: By the way, the $a$ from your question and the $a$ in your picture are different matrices. I assume that you meant for $a$ to be the one pictured.

Comment: Specifically, to prove linear independence, you should introduce *variables* for the coefficients and deduce that each must be zero. $$x\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} +y\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} +z\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}=0 \ \implies \ x=y=z=0$$

Comment: Unless you know that the dimension of this vector space is $3,$ you must also prove that these matrices span the vector space, i.e., every $2 \times 2$ symmetric matrix over $k$ can be written as a linear combination of these three matrices.

Comment: As @Berci says, by definition, these three matrices are linearly independent provided the only way to make $$ c_1 a + c_2 b + c_3 c = 0 $$ is to choose $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0$.  



See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#:~:text=In%20the%20theory%20of%20vector,said%20to%20be%20linearly%20independent.

Comment: I fixed the typo and am looking at the problem again. I'll get back in a bit once I have something more. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove linear independence, you should introduce *variables* for the coefficients (which you implicitly assumed to be $1$), and deduce that each must be zero.
$$x\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} +y\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} +z\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}=0 \ \implies \ x=y=z=0\,.$$
Then, you still have to prove that these three matrices form a *generating system* for the space of all symmetric matrices.

A more straightforward approach is to show them at once, i.e. that every symmetric matrix can be *uniquely* written as a linear combination of the given matrices.

> **Hint:** Just start off with an arbitrary symmetric matrix $\pmatrix{x&y\\y&z}$.

Comment: I suppose I'm stuck. I'm supposed to show that every 2x2 matrix can be a combination of x+y+z, but isn't that sort of implied already in the placement of a 1 in each matrix? If you choose a scaler and multiply it by 1, it's just the scaler. And since each of the four spots of a 2x2 vector have a 1 somewhere in one of the three vectors and zeroes in the rest, it means that any combination could be possible right?

Comment: We're talking about *symmetric* matrices, right? Then, yes, multiplying by $1$ and $0$ are easy, that's why we tend to choose such vectors (matrices) as basis..

Comment: I added a new pic where I made an attempt at your suggestion.

Comment: I don't understand what happens in your picture. The implication arrow is not equality sign. Why do you multiply your symmetric matrix by the basis elements? The coefficients in linear combination should be scalars (real numbers).